# Modify default action in a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint

to a list, I added a custom action that shows in the drop-down menu on AllItems.aspx and points to a custom page.

However, I want it to be the *default* action, so that clicking on the item doesn't go to DispForm.aspx

Any tip? Thanks

Comment: You should change your title to something like: Modify default action in a SharePoint List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I understood that while clicking on item from allitem.aspx you need to navigate to a custome page. You can do it in three ways

**1. Create a dataview webpart and customise the title item.**

**2. Using Javascript**

a. Edit the dispform.aspx page (add `&toolpaneview=2&sharedview=true` in in dispform.aspx url)

b.Closs the existing webpart

c.s Add a richtexteditor webpart and write a JavaScript to redirect to your custom page(`location.href=custompage.aspx`) .

Note: You can get the item id from the querystring using JavaScript if required.

**3. New Webpart** 
Instead of the custom page write a webpart, which has the functionality of your custom page, and add it in display form.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this by javascript on the allitems.aspx - edit the page, add content editor web part and follow these directions. the javascript is referencing the edit control block.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/09/04/customizing-the-sharepoint-ecb-with-javascript-part-2.aspx